# entry.get() from a fonction

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I want to get the value of the entry when I press the button, but I can't find a way to do it because the entry is in a fonction.

I tried to put a global before the entry but it doesn't work

```
#coding:utf-8
from Tkinter import *
from random import *


def nb1():
    nb=randint(0,16)
    jeu(nb)


def checkansw():
    answ = entryansw.get()
    if answ == int(nb, 2):
        showinfo('Résultat','Bravo !')
    restart()
    else:
        showwarning('Résultat','Incorrect !')
entryansw.set('')


def jeu(nb):
    nb=format(nb, 'b')
    root.destroy()
    root2 = Tk()
    root2.title("Binary Game")
    root2.geometry("500x350+50+50")
    root2.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    root2['bg'] = 'black'
    entryansw = Entry(root2, width=5, font=("Courier New", 20), 
justify=CENTER).pack(side=TOP, pady=30)
    boutonvalid = Button(root2, text="Valider", 
highlightbackground="black", command=checkansw).pack()
root2.mainloop()


root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x350+50+50")
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
root['bg'] = 'black'
choixdif = Label(root, pady=25, text="Veuillez choisir la 
difficulté.", font =("Courier New", 18), bg="black", 
fg="green").pack()
boutondif1 = Button(root, text="Facile", highlightbackground 
="black", command=nb1).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two parts to your problem. First is dealing with the scope of your variables. Like you said, you can declare `global` for variable `entryansw`:

```
def checkansw():
    global entryansw
    answ = entryansw.get()
    ...

def jeu(nb):
    global entryansw
    ...
```

Alternatively, you can first define a placeholder at your main function, and append the widget created by your function to the placeholder:

```
from tkinter import *

widget = []

def checkansw():
    answ = widget[0].get()
    if answ == int(nb, 2):
        pass
    else:
        widget[0].set('')

def jeu(nb):
    ...
    entryansw = Entry(root2, width=5, font=("Courier New", 20),justify=CENTER).pack(side=TOP, pady=30)
    widget.append(entryansw)
    ....
```

And of course, you can define a `class` to handle this instead:

```
class JEU:
    def __init__(self):
        nb=randint(0,16)
        self.jeu(nb)

    def checkansw(self):
        answ = self.entryansw.get()
        if answ == int(nb, 2):
            pass
        else:
            self.entryansw.set('')

    def jeu(self,nb):
        nb=format(nb, 'b')
        root.destroy()
        root2 = Tk()
        root2.title("Binary Game")
        root2.geometry("500x350+50+50")
        root2.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        root2['bg'] = 'black'
        self.entryansw = Entry(root2, width=5, font=("Courier New", 20),justify=CENTER).pack(side=TOP, pady=30)
        boutonvalid = Button(root2, text="Valider",highlightbackground="black", command=self.checkansw).pack()
        root2.mainloop()
```

Any of the above will solve the scope problem, however it still won't work because of the below code:

```
entryansw = Entry(root2, width=5, font=("Courier New", 20),justify=CENTER).pack(side=TOP, pady=30)
```

When you pack it directly, the variable `entryansw` becomes a reference to the `pack` method which is a None-type object:

```
<class 'NoneType'>
```

To properly refer to `entryansw`, you should call the pack method separately:

```
entryansw = Entry(root2, width=5, font=("Courier New", 20),justify=CENTER)
entryansw.pack(side=TOP, pady=30)
```

Now the type of `entryansw` becomes a proper widget.

```
<class 'tkinter.Entry'>
```

Still, there are a couple more things to improve for your code still, e.g. using `set` for your `entry` widget, calling `mainloop` twice...

Comment: I tried all but it didn't worked, I don't know if it's supposed to work with the full code or no. I still get error 

Here's the full code : https://github.com/Renegadepyth/ISN/blob/master/code

Answer (score 0):

You can get value from Entry by setting a text variable

```
entryansw_textvariable = StringVar()

entryansw = Entry(root2, width=5, font=("Courier New", 20), justify=CENTER, textvariable=entryansw_textvariable).pack(side=TOP, pady=30)

answ = entryansw_textvariable.get()
```

you can get details [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm)

Comment: This will have the exact same problem as in the question. You don't need a textvariable to get the value. What you need is a proper reference to the object. That is true whether the object is an entry widget or a stringvar.